# Javascript and Django issue, href tags not functional, loading templates inside of templates

Tags: javascript, html, django, frontend, backend

Alright guys, this is going to be a long shot, but this is what I’ve got going on. I’m building a website (both the front-end and back-end of the site) and I have been picking up where a current dev team left off. They built the front end of the site, and I am completing it. I am a bit new to front end development and back end development, but I’m making it happen even though it’s still a struggle.

Currently the site is laid out as so. There is an index.html file that acts a navigation for the site. It contains the dashboard for site navigation, a chat, and other features. This page is always visible. Other templates are loaded in the center of this index.html file via javascript (pretty much like an iframe, but not). Now, for whatever reason, the "a href" tags were not working when clicked, i.e. when they were clicked they would do nothing. I was able to fix this by adding the code below (or variation of this with proper references) to each template to be loaded inside of the index.html file. However, when clicking on a submit button in a form derived from django’s user authentication system, for example, it is not functional. I am able to manually put in the url i.e. (http://127.0.0.1:8000/thisisaurl - not loading url within index) and everything works so I know it's not my code (it’s not pretty, but it works). My question is, how can I make the buttons work with my setup? (i.e. if I click the submit button on the registration form in the template loaded in the center of the index file, how do I get it to work and not do nothing?) Is there a better way to do it than the javascript? Any input and advice is appreciated because as of now, I’m not even really sure what to look for. I apologize for the long setup, but I wanted to be as clear as possible. I apologize for any misuse of nomenclature or my ignorance in general ahead of time.

Also, why am I doing it this way? Because it looks awesome and it's really unique.

That being said, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you ahead of time.

My code is below:

Javascript code that makes the a href tags functional:

```
$(function(){

$('').on('click', function( e ){   
});

var wrap = $('content');


$('#splash a').on('click', function( e ) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    wrap.load( href + '' )
    .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
    e.preventDefault();
});


});
```

Template with registration form in it and javascript in context (once again, lots of content has been removed for viewing ease):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.advancedSlider.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="registerbox_new">
                <p class="register_header">Register Below</p>
                        <div class="registration_form">
                                    {% block content %}
                                        <form action="/register_temp/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

                                                <ul style="position:relative; top:20px;">
                                                    <li id="username_registration"><p>Username:</p>{{ form.username }}</li> 
                                                    <li id="email_registration" class=""><p>Email:</p>{{ form.email}}</li>
                                                    <li id="password1_registration" class=""><p>Password:</p>{{ form.password1 }}</li>
                                                    <li id="password2_registration" class=""><p>Password confirmation:</p>{{ form.password2 }}</li>
                                                </ul>

                                            <input class="registration_button" type="submit" value="Register" style="position:relative; left:55px;" />

                                        </form>
                                    {% endblock %}
                        </div>

                            <div class="socialregistration">
                                <p class="socialregistration_header">Social Registration</p>
                                <a href=""><img class="socialreg" src="/static/img/roundsocialfacebook.png" alt=""></a> 
                                <a href=""><img class="socialreg" src="/static/img/roundsocialtwitter.png" alt=""></a>   
                            </div>

                                <div class="test">
                                    <a href="/register_login/"><p style="position:relative; top:45px; left:175px; color:#FFF; font-weight:bold;"> or Login >></p></a>
                                </div>
                    </div>


            </div>



    </div><!--box-->
</div><!--splash-->



<script>

$(function(){

    $('').on('click', function( e ){   
    });

    var wrap = $('content');


    $('#splash a').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The index.html file (many lines of code have been redacted for ease of reading):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/img/atmosphere_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/profile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/advanced-slider-base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/small-round-button.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/static/css/hover.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-ui.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/scroll.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.transition.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.advancedSlider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/simplyScroll.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.marquee.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.pause.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.webticker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/engine.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>




<!-- start soundmanager2 -->
<!-- demo, make the fonts nicer etc. -->


<!-- soundManager.useFlashBlock: related CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/flashblock.css" />

<!-- soundmanager required -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/360player.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/360player-visualization.css" />

<!-- sound manager Apache-licensed animation library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/berniecode-animator.js"></script>

<!-- soundmanager core stuff -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/soundmanager2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/360player.js"></script>


<!-- google analytics start -->
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-61687738-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- google analytics end -->

</head>

<body leftmargin="auto" topmargin="auto" marginwidth="auto" marginheight="auto">
<div id="wrapper">

<a class="logout" href="viewmore/">View More</a>
    <img class="atmov1_img" src="/static/img/atmov1_4.png">




<!-- Load Content -->
<content class="loadContent">
</content>



<script>

$(function() {
    /* Page Load */
    $('body').keyup(function(event) {
        $('div.popup').hide();
        $('div.popup:nth-child('+(event.which-47)+')').show();
        switch(event.which) {
            case 56:
                $('div.popup.friendPics div.friendPicsCont').slimScroll({ 
                    height: '370px',
                    width: '350px',
                    position: 'right',
                    railVisible: false,
                    alwaysVisible: true,
                    railColor: '#4f4c6a',
                    opacity: .7,
                    color: '#4f4c6a'
                });
                break;
        }
    });


});
</script>

</body>
</HTML>
```

Example of html file with button that is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/profile.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.advancedSlider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/simplyScroll.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/static/css/hover.css">
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>


<div class="page" id="pointsPage">

    <p class="pointspage_header">Create Comment!</p>
            <div style="position:relative; height:300px; width:300px; ">
                {% block content %}
                <form action="/userprofile/create/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    <ul>
                    {{ form.as_ul }}
                    </ul>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Comment">
                </form>
                {% endblock %}
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: adding an id and name to the form and button in combination with some js was able to fix my button issue partially. However the results from the form submission are being loaded into a separate page that takes the user away from the index. (the template is not being loaded inside of the index). I will list the code below. Anybody savvy with javascript that could think of a fix?

The html:

```
<input name="registerform" id="registerform" class="registration_button" type="submit" value="Register" style="position:relative; left:55px;" onclick="userform();" />
```

the js:

```
<script> 
function userform() 
{ document.getElementById('registerform').submit(); } 
</script>
```

Obviously this is only a temporary, duct tape fix, and I will think of a better way in the future, but for now this saves me a bunch of headache. Thank you everyone once again!

Comment: Is there no `base.html` file? Usually the navigation links which are common to all pages are stored in the `base.html` and a container loads the individual pages.

Comment: as of now there is no base.html file. I'm not sure if it would be advantageous to do it that way because the pages loaded in the center of the index do not have that many commonalities in design. Do you think that would be the way to go? The front and dev team before me set it up this way and I continued with that as I have been building this out. Also, I have many features in the index that can't be refreshed such as a music player and chat.

Comment: Are all links not working or just a subset of them?

Comment: I always use a `base.html` to reuse code. its very good to use. You can write all your navigation code in the `base.html` file.

Comment: I'm not sure if loading ALL pages using javascript is good way at all.

Comment: @sam p, at first nothing worked, then when I added the js listed above (first bit of code listed) I was able to get all of the links functional except the ones derived from django views. (Ex. Django registration/authentication). For some reason the JavaScript loading content is messing it up.

Comment: @ k neeraj Yeah I'm not a fan of the js either. But will I be able to have the content load within the index.html as a base file? Ultimately will that do the same thing?

Comment: @user3700231 could you edit your post with a couple of examples of links that are current working, and a couple of ones that aren't? Then we can look at a full example.

Comment: @ sam p ex: in the template posted above that contains the registration form, this button does not work: <input class="registration_button" type="submit" value="Register" style="position:relative; left:55px;" /> This is derived from the login/registration views. However, a normal href link will work such as: <a href="/register_login/"><p style="position:relative; top:45px; left:175px; color:#FFF; font-weight:bold;"> or Login >></p></a> and this is because I added the js code listed at the very top of this page. Basically all django stuff does not work in center of index. Pure html does.

Comment: @SamP I added an example of a button that is not working also. Like I said, the django stuff is the only stuff not working, but when I manually type in the url and the page isn't loaded inside the index, the django stuff works just like it should, which would lead me to assume it's the javascript messing it up somehow. I just don't know the fix. The js code I added enabled the pure html href tags to work but was not sufficient for fixing the buttons with django derived content.

Comment: @samp @K Neeraj Lal, I was able to get the button working by adding some javascript.  The html: `<input name="registerform" id="registerform" class="registration_button" type="submit" value="Register" style="position:relative; left:55px;" onclick="userform();" />` and `<script>
        function userform() {
        document.getElementById('registerform').submit();
        }
    </script>` Now the only problem is that when the form is submitted, the result is loaded in a separate page instead of within the center of the index file. Anybody savy with javascript that could think of a fix?

Comment: @user3700231 this is a very specific problem so is quite hard to answer without looking at the code and running through some examples. If you're having to use javascript just to get core functionality working (and Django is supposed to be providing it) then something is broken somewhere, or there is a misunderstanding of what role Django is playing here (e.g. is it only serving ajax or normal requests as well?). It's probably worth getting to the real root of the problem, figuring out what Django should be doing and significantly simplifying your code before continuing to build on top of it.